# Regex dash means subtract/negative/or just dash detection

Tags: php, regex

Is there an easier way to detect whether a dash means subtract/negative/or is just a dash than running separate regex pattern searches for each pattern?

ie;

```
4-word = dash
word-4 = dash
word-word = dash
4-4 = minus
-4 = negative
```

is it possible to combine this into one regex search? or I must use different searches for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this lookarounds based regex for this:

```
-(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?<!^)-
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ6mG5/1)

```
-           # Match a literal
(?=\D)      # Lookahead that means match a literal - if not followed by a non-digit
|           # regex alternation (OR)
(?<=\D)     # Lookbehind that means if not preceded by a non-digit
(?!^)       # Negative Lookahead that means not preceded by line start
-           # Match a literal -
```

Comment: Ah you can use OR within regex, perfect, thank you for this. I never used regex very much so I'm not 100% with it, thank you.